# Is there a way to create Greater than equal to in BATCH

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to make the system check if the value is Greater than or Equal to a certain number. I am trying to create an RPG and if the Health goes to 0 then I would like it to go to another section.

I have tried this

```
If "%playerhealth%"== "0' goto checkpoint
```

This is my whole code

```
:firstfight
color 04
echo FIGHT!!!
pause
cls
color 0F
echo Player %playerhealth%          Enemy %foehealth%
echo --------
echo.
echo 1) FIGHT!!!
echo 2) QUIT :(
echo.
set /p battleoption=What will %name% do
if "%battleoption%"== "1" goto result1
if "%battleoption%"== "2" goto youlose
if "%foehealth%"== "0" goto youwin1
if %playerhealth% EQU 0 goto gameover
goto result1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF %playerhealth% GEQ 0 goto :checkpoint
```

quotes enforces a string comparison so you need to remove them.
For more info check `IF /?`

Comment: For "greater than *or equal*" use GEQ instead of GTR.

Comment: Thank you. Wish I had enough Reputation to upvote you

Comment: Remove your quotes (and your single quote) for arithmetic comparison. Use quotes for string comparison.

Comment: Hey npocmaka, you should indicated that quotes enforces a string comparison, so the OP needs to remove them! **`;)`**